# How to use Obj-C "sender" method in Nativescript

Tags: objective-c, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Unable to use sender method in nativescript. I just want to convert blow code into nativescript with angular 2 .

Objective-c Code :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    NSLog(@"got auth challange");

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        _Authenticated = YES;
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:pusername password:ppassword  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel auth challange");

        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    }
}

[[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:pusername password:ppassword  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

NativeScript Angular 2 code:

```
  var MyNSURLConnectionDelegate = NSURLConnection.extend({
                connectionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: function (connection, challenge) {

                    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
                        _self._Authenticated = true;
                        //var nsURLCredential = NSURLCredential.credentialWithUserPasswordPersistence("phoneuser", "phoneuser", NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent);

                        challenge.sender.useCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(NSURLCredential.credentialWithUserPasswordPersistence("phoneuser", "phoneuser", NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent), challenge);
                        // [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:pusername password:ppassword  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Cancel auth challange");
                        _self.loader.hide();


                        challenge.sender.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge);
                        // [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

                    }



                }
```

error message : JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'challenge.sender.useCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge'

How to use above code inside nativescript.. any one have idea.

Comment: Obviously `challenge` is not defined, and it is nowhere to be seen from what little part you shared of your code.

Comment: I just want to convert objective c to nativescript one line code

Comment: i'm able to convert the code but sender how to use in nativescript